# Can I use aws:PrincipalOrgID with a service principal

Tags: amazon-web-services

Hi guys please can i use PrincipalOrgID with AWS service principal the way I used it with Cloudtrail below in my policy?

```
"Sid":"Allow Cloudtrail to encrypt logs",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal":{
            "Service":"cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition":{
            "StringEquals":{
                "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "${var.organization_id}"
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. `cloudtrail` is AWS service, not part of your `organization`. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-principalorgid):

> This key is included in the request context only if the **principal is a member of an organization**.

Comment: thanks for your reponse...please how can i reference accounts in my organization without having to write them out individually